# SQL query to check the last day of the month is not a sunday

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I want to calculate the last day of the month, but if this date is a sunday then the below query should not give any output.

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) = SYSDATE
```

I am using it in a trigger hence I only want the above query it give an output when the last day of the month is not a sunday.  Which function to use to get the day of the month or to tweak this query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
select 1
from dual
where to_char(last_day(sysdate),'D') != 1;
```

Depending on your NLS-settings you may have to change the constant or use an NLS-parameter in to_char().

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 common ways to check the day of week:

1. Most obvious and simple thing is to specify you nls_date_language and use weekday names:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate,'day','nls_date_language=English') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DAY','NLS_DATE_LANG
------------------------------------
friday

1 row selected.

SQL> select to_char(sysdate,'day','nls_date_language=French') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DAY','NLS_DATE_
--------------------------------
vendredi

1 row selected.
```

So you can use

```
SQL> select 'ok' x from dual where to_char(sysdate,'fmday','nls_date_language=English')='friday';

X
--
ok

1 row selected.
```

NB. Do not forget to use 'fm' to trim white spaces, ie 'friday' and not `'friday    '`:

```sql
SQL> select '['||to_char(sysdate,'day','nls_date_language=English')||']' from dual;

'['||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DAY','NLS_DATE_L
--------------------------------------
[friday   ]

1 row selected.

SQL> select '['||to_char(sysdate,'fmday','nls_date_language=English')||']' from dual;

'['||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'FMDAY','NLS_DATE
--------------------------------------
[friday]

1 row selected.
```

2. Another way is to use numeric day format, but in this case your day number depends on nls_terrory, for example:

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/o4i3rlBp

```
SQL> alter session set nls_territory=America;

Session altered.

with first_10_of_2020 as (
select date'2020-01-01'+level-1 dt from dual connect by level<=10
)
select 
   to_char(dt,'yyyy-mm-dd') dt
  ,to_char(dt,'day','nls_date_language=''English''') day_en
  ,to_char(dt, 'd', 'nls_date_language=''NUMERIC DATE LANGUAGE''') d_1
from first_10_of_2020;

DT         DAY_EN                               D
---------- ------------------------------------ -
2020-01-01 wednesday                            4
2020-01-02 thursday                             5
2020-01-03 friday                               6
2020-01-04 saturday                             7
2020-01-05 sunday                               1
2020-01-06 monday                               2
2020-01-07 tuesday                              3
2020-01-08 wednesday                            4
2020-01-09 thursday                             5
2020-01-10 friday                               6

10 rows selected.

SQL> alter session set nls_territory=France;

Session altered.

with first_10_of_2020 as (
select date'2020-01-01'+level-1 dt from dual connect by level<=10
)
select 
   to_char(dt,'yyyy-mm-dd') dt
  ,to_char(dt,'day','nls_date_language=''English''') day_en
  ,to_char(dt, 'd', 'nls_date_language=''NUMERIC DATE LANGUAGE''') d_1
from first_10_of_2020;

DT         DAY_EN                               D
---------- ------------------------------------ -
2020-01-01 wednesday                            3
2020-01-02 thursday                             4
2020-01-03 friday                               5
2020-01-04 saturday                             6
2020-01-05 sunday                               7
2020-01-06 monday                               1
2020-01-07 tuesday                              2
2020-01-08 wednesday                            3
2020-01-09 thursday                             4
2020-01-10 friday                               5

10 rows selected.
```

As you can see in case of NLS_TERRITORY=America, Friday is 6, while in case of France it's 5. So to make it more reliable you can use ISO weeks, ie you can use > ['IW' format model](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A):

> IW: Calendar week of year (1-52 or 1-53), as defined by the ISO 8601 standard.
>
> A calendar week starts on Monday.
>
> The first calendar week of the year includes January 4.
>
> The first calendar week of the year may include December 29, 30 and 31.
>
> The last calendar week of the year may include January 1, 2, and 3.

So you can use `trunc(dt)-trunc(dt,'iw')+1` and it doesn't depend on your nls_language/nls_territory: Monday is always 1 and Sunday is always 7:

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/zVS2vcjK

```sql
SQL> alter session set nls_territory=America;

Session altered.

with first_10_of_2020 as (
select date'2020-01-01'+level-1 dt from dual connect by level<=10
)
select 
   to_char(dt,'yyyy-mm-dd') dt
  ,to_char(dt,'day','nls_date_language=''English''') day_en
  ,trunc(dt)-trunc(dt,'iw')+1 as d_1
from first_10_of_2020;

DT         DAY_EN                                 D_1
---------- ------------------------------------ -----
2020-01-01 wednesday                                3
2020-01-02 thursday                                 4
2020-01-03 friday                                   5
2020-01-04 saturday                                 6
2020-01-05 sunday                                   7
2020-01-06 monday                                   1
2020-01-07 tuesday                                  2
2020-01-08 wednesday                                3
2020-01-09 thursday                                 4
2020-01-10 friday                                   5

10 rows selected.

SQL> alter session set nls_territory=France;

Session altered.

with first_10_of_2020 as (
select date'2020-01-01'+level-1 dt from dual connect by level<=10
)
select 
   to_char(dt,'yyyy-mm-dd') dt
  ,to_char(dt,'day','nls_date_language=''English''') day_en
  ,trunc(dt)-trunc(dt,'iw')+1 as d_1
from first_10_of_2020;

DT         DAY_EN                                 D_1
---------- ------------------------------------ -----
2020-01-01 wednesday                                3
2020-01-02 thursday                                 4
2020-01-03 friday                                   5
2020-01-04 saturday                                 6
2020-01-05 sunday                                   7
2020-01-06 monday                                   1
2020-01-07 tuesday                                  2
2020-01-08 wednesday                                3
2020-01-09 thursday                                 4
2020-01-10 friday                                   5

10 rows selected.
```